# Overriding media queries of parent css in wordpress child-theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass, media-queries

I want to create a child-theme of a responsive wordpress-theme. The parent theme's css defines  somes media queries like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { /* a bunch of changes */ }
```

Now let's say I would like the breakpoint to be at 900px instead of 1000px. Is there any way to easily override this in my child-theme's css?

Comment: You can't reset/overwrite CSS within a media query unless you overwrite every single, individual element and property. Is it not possible to just change the initial query?

Comment: Ok that's what I was thinking too. I could of course override the original parent-css, but I would have to do that again every time the parent-theme gets updated :/ thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**JoshC** is absolutely correct.

Probably you do not understand the idea - **media query** is nost some kind of rule like in css. This is more glogal understanding.

Let's say:

you have media query in main theme

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { #main{color:#000;} }
```

You set div with **ID main** to have text color **BLACK** but only if maximum browser width is not more then **1000px - (max-width: 1000px)**

Wherever you use this query - it will work same way.

What you need to specify is the stuff inside, for example to make the following more important use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { #main{color:#000 !important;} }
```

Comment: So if I want to use 900px instead can I use @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { !important } in the child to ignore ALL the settings that the parent uses for 1000px