# How to override media query in child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I want to override a media query in my wordpress child theme. It's currently set at max-width: 1024px, but I want it to trigger at far less, say 700px. The problem is if I set a new media query at 700px, yes the 700px media query is activated, but it does not override the max-width:1024px, this one is still being acknowledged. If i wanted to override with a max-width that's larger than 1024px then there would be no problem, but as I'm going smaller, how do I tell it to ignore the 1024px media query in the parent theme's css?

I don't want to edit the parent theme as I'll lose changes on updates. Have looked in other threads such as this:

[Overriding media queries of parent css in wordpress child-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965809/overriding-media-queries-of-parent-css-in-wordpress-child-theme)

But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Post the two CSS rules in question please.

Comment: Have you tried `!important` at 700px

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the rules set for `@media (max-width: 1024px)` to the child stylesheet file.
2. Rewrite the media query to `@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1024px)`
3. Now use your custom rules `@media (max-width: 700px)` in child style.css after rewritten styles.

```css
/* Style.css rewritten */

@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .color {
    color: lightblue;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
/* Child.css */

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .color {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="color">I can change my color and position only after 700px and before 1024px</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand how adding "(min-width: 700px) and" will stop the parent media query from running

Comment: Not really sure. Seeing this after a very long gap.